# Варево и месиво: выбор суффикса ЕВ/ИВ

Tags: суффиксы

В этих словах суффиксы ЕВ/ИВ не различаются по значению (в обоих случаях это предмет, который подвергается действию или является результатом действия), поэтому их рекомендуется проверять по словарю (также: курево, месиво, топливо, чтиво).

А какова история орфографии таких слов, как она связана с грамматикой, менялось ли их написание при проведении реформ?

Answer (score 1):

> ...их рекомендуется проверять по словарю (также: курево, месиво,
>   топливо, **чтиво**).

А ***чтиво***-то зачем по словарю проверять?

Comment: Чтиво - для образца, приведена для примера  сильная позиция гласного в этом суффиксе. Может быть, выбор ЕВ/ИВ как-то с основой связан? Такая же проблема есть и для суффиксов ЕВ/ИВ прилагательных, но там ЕВ - безударный, а ИВ ударный, кроме исключений.